# CSS Sliding Doors Not Working

Tags: html, css

This is probably a dumb question but can't find an answer with google.  Left side of the image shows up fine, can't for the life of me get the right image to show.

HTML/CSS Newb, just learning the basics.

http://bungle.ca/
http://bungle.ca/images/

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link Six</a></li>
</ul>

#nav{
min-width:  1024px;
height: 30px;
padding:    0px;
margin: 0px;
color:  #eeeeee;
white-space:    nowrap;
list-style-type:    none;
}

#nav li{
display:    inline;
background: url('../images/tabRight.png') no-repeat right   top;
}

#nav li a{
padding:    .2em    1em;
height: 30px;
width:  100px;
text-decoration:    none;
float:  left;
text-align: center;
background: url('../images/tabLeft.png')    no-repeat   left    top;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `display:inline-block;` to #nav li

Comment: Thanks!  Can't believe they don't include that at class.

Answer (score 0):

The padding in `#nav li a` is allowing the tabLeft background image to overlay on top of tabRight background image in `#nav li`.

Try adding `margin-right: 10px;` to the `#nav li a` element, where 10px is the actual width of the tabRight.png image. Alternatively you could add `padding-right: 10px;` to the `#nav li` element. You'll need to adjust the right padding for `#nav li a` accordingly so the button is the appropriate dimensions.

Here is the sliding doors code I've always used:

```
<li><a href="#" class="oneup">See Our Breads</a></li>

li {
    background: url(img/button_gold_right.gif) top right no-repeat;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0; /* 10px is width of _right.gif image)
    display: block;
    height: 23px; /* height & line-height the same so text centered vertically */
    line-height: 23px;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    background: url(img/button_gold_left.gif) top left no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px; /* 10px on left so text is centered horizontally */
}
```

Comment: I'll post my sliding doors code in a moment, hopefully you can adapt :)

Comment: It looks like what's happening in your example is the `float:left` property of `#nav li a` is not cleared, so the background image won't show through. You can try adding `overflow:auto;` to your `#nav li` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Aside:** A good method to debug your CSS is to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the Inspect element in Mozilla or Chrome. To trigger inspect element right click on your browser and hit inspect element. On the right, you can modify the css by changing the attributes and you can view specific css attributes for each element by clicking that element in the inspect element console.

Looking at your nav li, it's dimensions are currently 0 by 0 so there is no space for the image to show up

If you change your code to

```
    #nav li{
    display:    block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../images/tabRight.png') no-repeat right   top;
    }
```

you can now see your tabRight image.